# Optical Flow on Water

Tags: visual-c++, computer-vision, opticalflow

I am currently doing a project that involves applying optical flow to Ocean waves. Are there any suggestions for papers that I should read to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe Bernd Jahne has some papers specifically about applying optical flow to ocean waves.  I know there is some discussion of this in his "Spatio-temporal Image Processing" book and his "Digital Image Processing" book.